# What webserver to support android application?

Tags: android, webserver

I have made an android application that has the capability to get some user input (eg. text, photos etc) and post it to a web server.
What is the recommended type of webserver to support such an android application?
I mean like joomla, java or spring server or any other?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to try something new then I recommend you look at https://parse.com/ or https://www.stackmob.com/. They are platforms that makes getting your app up and running incredibly easy.

For what you want to accomplish there are a ton of possibilities. I would pick the one that aligns most closely with your existing skills. I really like node.js/MongoDB as a stack but others prefer running a traditional JAX-RS MySQL backend.

It really comes down to how much you want to spend on hosting and what you know/are willing to learn. You are not doing anything that requires a special or unique technology stack.

Comment: Thank you very much rdrobinson3